# How to vertical Flip YUV420p bytes stream?

Tags: image-processing, yuv

I really really want to know about flip algorithm about YUV420P(IYUV) byte stream.

I knew flip algorithm of RGB or RGBA Byte stream... but yuv420 format didn't...

I tried to find any example bur I didn't...

How can I flip the yuv420p stream?

[Edit]
My project use C/C++ language!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#/media/File:Yuv420.svg The format is planar, so basically you could take the first 2/3 of each frame's pixels and flip it like a normal greyscale image, then take the next 1/6 of the pixels and flip them as a greyscale (remembering the width and height are halved) and likewise for the last 1/6th of the pixels.

Comment: It might help if you mentioned what environment you use? C++? Python? PIL? The Microsoft Csharp thing? OpenCV? Java?